# Document Information Panel was unable to load: NodeTest expected here

Tags: 2013, document-library, metadata, word

We are using SP built-in feature to map document library columns to Word QuickParts. We are using default template for Microsoft Office applications.

Most of Word templates are working fine, but several do not behave as expected. When I open the document by clicking the link in document library, the document is loaded in Word client application, but Document Information Panel is unable to load. This prevents me from saving the document back to document library.

This is the error thrown by Word client application:

> The form cannot be opened. To fix this problem, contact the form
>   designer.
>   Form template:
>   http://servername/sites/sitename/proppanel.xsn
>   Document
>   Information Panel cannot open the following view: ContentType Properties
>   - Server
>   The following view file is not valid: view2.xsl
>   The .xsl file is not valid XSL.
>   NodeTest expected here.
>
> @<--

The only tool which I have used for debugging purposes was Fiddler so far.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I located the faulty site column by excluding one by one site column from content type.

Not a nice solution but at least I was able to pin point the site column which was causing problems. Unfortunately it took me around 15 deploys to isolate the problem.